# How do I remove the space between QPlainTextEdit and its contents?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qplaintextedit, qtextbrowser

I'm using C++ and Qt on Windows to create a simple application which outputs some data to the screen using a `QPlainTextEdit`.

The problem is that there is a small internal margin between the `QPlainTextEdit`'s border and the text as shown here:

[image]

The text in the `QPlainTextEdit` has been selected to highlight the gap.

I have tried using `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` and `setStyleSheet("padding:0;")`, and using a `QTextEdit` or a `QTextBrowser` instead, but I still get that small margin.

Googling it only turned up [this unanswered question on qtcentre.org](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56908-Text-margin-in-QTextEdit).

Comment: Qt controls vary in looks to mimic the look and feel of native platform widgets so you may want to dig into the implementation details of whatever platform(s) you target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [QTextDocument::setDocumentMargin()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop). Setting it to zero does the trick. To obtain [QTextDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) there's a method [QPlainTextEdit::document()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document).

Comment: This is the answer!  Setting margin or padding in style sheet does not work in Qt 5 and probably other versions.

Comment: Not work for me.

Comment: @ChrisP That's not the margin you intend.